# overloading pre-increment operator not showing correct result

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, friend-function, unary-operator

I've overloaded the pre-increment operator using friend function. In the overloaded friend function, the value of the variable is showing correct. But that value is not shown in display function, why?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
public:
    int breadth;

public:
    void read();
    void display();
    friend void operator ++(Rectangle r1);
};
void Rectangle::read()
{
    cout << "Enter the breadth of the Rectangle: ";
    cin >> breadth;
}
void operator++(Rectangle r1)
{
    ++r1.breadth;
    cout<<r1.breadth<<endl; //correct result
}
void Rectangle::display()
{
    cout<<breadth<<endl; // not showing pre-incremented value, why ???
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"Unary Operator using Friend Function \n";
    Rectangle r1;
    r1.read();
    ++r1;
    cout << "\n breadth of Rectangle after increment: ";
    r1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is "Rectangle r1" - a pointer, a reference, or a copied object based on the one you passed in?

Comment: Because your ++ operator is a non-member function and increments its own copy of the rectangle.

Comment: You should implement the ++ operator as a member function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `operator ++` takes the `Rectangle` object by value, which means it receives a *copy* of its operand. It then dutifully increments the copy's `breadth` member, prints it out, and then discards the copy when it's over.

You'll want to take the parameter by reference:

```
friend void operator ++(Rectangle &r1)
{
  ++r1.breadth;
}
```

Also note that it's quite common to overload unary operators using member functions instead of free functions. Used like that, you wouldn't have this problem:

```
class Rectangle
{
  // ...

public:
  void operator++ ()
  {
    ++breadth;
  }

  // ...
};
```

A few side comments:

- It's common for `operator++` to return a reference to its operand, to mimic what built-in operators do. Just like it's possible to do `++ ++ i` for an `int i`, it should be possible to do `++ ++ r` for a user-defined type `r` as well.
- In practice, operator overloading should only be used when a) you're writing a type which behaves similarly to a built-in type, or b) you're writing a domain-specific language. Incrementing a rectangle is not something I could intuitively explain, and would be best done as a named member function. How can you tell whether `++r` increases the breadth, or height, or both, or moves the rectangle to the right, or ...?

Comment: You should also show the solution for having the increment overload as a member function.

Comment: @tambre If you wanted to show how to do it right, you'd refer to the [FAQ entry on operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading).

Comment: That last bullet point is *hugely* important.  This is a very poor use of operating overloading.  (With luck, it is a poor choice of example problem by a teacher).